# HTML/CSS - Match Two Label/Input Widths on Same Line

Tags: html, css

I am trying to have two labels with corresponding inputs be on the same line with the same width, currently, the width is messing up when in a relatively small container.

Example of widths in small container:

[image]

Code:

```css
#row {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: nowrap;
    margin-top:4px;
}

#row label {
    display:block;
    width:25%;
    height:30px; 
    line-height:30px; 
    text-align:center;
}

#row input {
    width: 75%;
    border: 1px solid rgb(116, 115, 115);
    padding-left:3px;
}
```

```html
<div id="row">
  <label for="start">Start</label>
  <input name="start" id="start" />
  <label for="end">End</label>
  <input name="end" id="endTime"/>
</div>
```

The difference is minimal, but noticeable. Any suggestions?

Comment: They are the same width...you can check it in the inspector. What I suspect you are seeing is an illusion caused by the differing text widths.

Comment: I think you might be wright. I just inspected each one and checked their widths! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to have same width input box then try using min-width property like:

```
#row input {
    min-width: 250px;
    border: 1px solid rgb(116, 115, 115);
    padding-left:3px;
}
```

BTW they both look the same.

Answer (score 0):

The widths are the same, my eyes were playing tricks on me.